# Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Use the Euclidean Algorithm to compute $gcd(7k+14; 3k+6)$.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I hope the latex above works in the title...

If k is a positive integer, compute gcd(7k+14, 3k+6), using the Euclidean Algorithm.

I'm having some difficulty with the treatment of the variable in this context, and would appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Just use the form $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$.

The Euclidean Algorithm is just an abbreviation of this process.

Comment: so
$gcd(7k+14;3k+6) = gcd(4k+8;3k+6) = gcd(k+2;3k+6) = gcd(k+2;k+2) = k+2$?

Comment: therefore $gcd(7k+14;3k+6) = k+2$

Comment: @MikeWasTaken, yes!